# Вывод DIV в опредленном месте php

Tags: php, joomla

Есть необходимость вывести Div в определенном месте сайта
Например после элемента 6:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытки перебрать элементы массива items и на 7 элемент вывести какой-то div не увенчались успехом:

```
<?php if(count($this->items)): ?> 
<div class="tagItemList">
    <?php 
          $i = 0; 
          foreach($this->items as $item): 
                 if (++$i==7):
                      echo "<div>Мой див</div>";
                  endif;
    ?>
```

Div либо не выводится, либо выводится хаотично (то есть $i не соответствует реальной позиции в шаблоне)
Есть ли какие то альтернативные методы решения задачи?

в пхп не силен, спасибо за помощь.

Прилагаю весь код:

```
    <?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$pagdata = $this->pagination->getData();
if($pagdata->next->link){
    $doc->addHeadLink( $pagdata->next->link, 'next');
}
if($pagdata->previous->link){
    $doc->addHeadLink( $pagdata->previous->link, 'prev');
}

?>

    <!-- Start K2 Tag Layout -->
<div id="k2Container" class="tagView<?php     if($this->params->get('pageclass_sfx')) echo ' '.$this->params->get('pageclass_sfx'); ?>">

<?php if($this->params->get('show_page_title')): ?>
    <!-- Page title -->
    <h1 class="componentheading<?php echo  $this->params->get('pageclass_sfx')?>">
        <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_title')); ?>
    </h1>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(count($this->items)): ?>
    <div class="tagItemList">
        <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach($this->items as $item):
            if (++$i==7):
                echo "<div>Мой див</div>";
            endif;
            ?>

            <!-- Start K2 Item Layout -->
            <div class="tagItemView">



                <div class="tagItemBody">
                    <?php if($item->params->get('tagItemImage',1) && !empty($item->imageSmall)): ?>
                        <!-- Item Image -->
                        <div class="tagItemImageBlock">
              <span class="tagItemImage">
                <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" title="<?php  if(!empty($item->image_caption)) echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->image_caption); else echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->title); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $item->imageMedium; ?>" alt="<?php if(!empty($item->image_caption)) echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->image_caption); else echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->title); ?>" style="width:<?php echo $item->params->get('_itemMedium'); ?>px; height:auto;" />
                </a>
              </span>
                            <div class="clr"></div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="tagItemHeader">
                        <?php if($item->params->get('tagItemDateCreated',1)): ?>
                            <!-- Date created -->
                            <span class="tagItemDateCreated">
                <?php echo JHTML::_('date', $item->created , JText::_('K2_DATE_FORMAT_LC2')); ?>
            </span>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if($item->params->get('tagItemTitle',1)): ?>
                            <!-- Item title -->
                            <p class="tag-title-box">
                                <?php if ($item->params->get('tagItemTitleLinked',1)): ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $item->title; ?>
                                    </a>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <?php echo $item->title; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="introTags">

                        <!-- Item introTag -->
                        <?php
                        $tags = K2ModelItem::getItemTags($item->id,3);
                        for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($tags); $i++) {
                            $tags[$i]->link =  JRoute::_(K2HelperRoute::getTagRoute($tags[$i]->name));
                        }
                        $item->tags=$tags;
                        ?>
                        <div class="introTagsBlock">
                            <?php if(count($item->tags)): ?>


                                <!-- Item tags -->
                                <span class="intro-cool-tags">
               <?php $counter = 0; ?>
                                    <?php foreach ($item->tags as $tag): ?>
                                        <?php if (++$counter > 3) break; ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $tag->link; ?>">#<?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
               </span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>

                        <?php if($item->params->get('tagItemIntroText',1)): ?>
                            <!-- Item introtext -->
                            <div class="tagItemIntroText">
                                <?php
                                $text = $item->introtext;
                                $max_lengh = 180;

                                if(mb_strlen($text, "UTF-8") > $max_lengh) {
                                    $text_cut = mb_substr($text, 0, $max_lengh, "UTF-8");
                                    $text_explode = explode(" ", $text_cut);

                                    unset($text_explode[count($text_explode) - 1]);

                                    $text_implode = implode(" ", $text_explode);

                                    echo $text_implode."...";
                                } else {
                                    echo $text; }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <div class="clr"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="clr"></div>

                <?php if($item->params->get('tagItemExtraFields',0) && count($item->extra_fields)): ?>
                    <!-- Item extra fields -->
                    <div class="tagItemExtraFields">
                        <h4><?php echo JText::_('K2_ADDITIONAL_INFO'); ?></h4>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ($item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField): ?>
                                <?php if($extraField->value != ''): ?>
                                    <li class="<?php echo ($key%2) ? "odd" : "even"; ?> type<?php echo ucfirst($extraField->type); ?> group<?php echo $extraField->group; ?>">
                                        <?php if($extraField->type == 'header'): ?>
                                            <h4 class="tagItemExtraFieldsHeader"><?php echo $extraField->name; ?></h4>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <span class="tagItemExtraFieldsLabel"><?php echo $extraField->name; ?></span>
                                            <span class="tagItemExtraFieldsValue"><?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if($item->params->get('tagItemCategory')): ?>
                    <!-- Item category name -->
                    <div class="tagItemCategory">
                        <span><?php echo JText::_('K2_PUBLISHED_IN'); ?></span>
                        <a href="<?php echo $item->category->link; ?>"><?php echo $item->category->name; ?></a>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($item->params->get('tagItemReadMore')): ?>
                    <!-- Item "read more..." link -->
                    <div class="tagItemReadMore">
                        <a class="k2ReadMore" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">
                            <?php echo JText::_('K2_READ_MORE'); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="clr"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- End K2 Item Layout -->

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Pagination -->
    <div class="k2Pagination">
        <p><?php if($this->pagination->getPagesLinks()): ?></p>
        <?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks(); ?>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <?php/* echo $this->pagination->getPagesCounter();*/ ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

    <!--Social-->
    <script type="text/javascript">(function(w,doc) {
            if (!w.__utlWdgt ) {
                w.__utlWdgt = true;
                var d = doc, s = d.createElement('script'), g = 'getElementsByTagName';
                s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.charset='UTF-8'; s.async = true;
                s.src = ('https:' == w.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http')  + '://w.uptolike.com/widgets/v1/uptolike.js';
                var h=d[g]('body')[0];
                h.appendChild(s);
            }})(window,document);
    </script>
    <div data-background-alpha="0.0" data-buttons-color="#ffffff" data-counter-background-color="#ffffff" data-share-counter-size="16" data-top-button="false" data-share-counter-type="common" data-share-style="1" data-mode="share" data-like-text-enable="false" data-hover-effect="rotate-cw" data-mobile-view="true" data-icon-color="#ffffff" data-orientation="fixed-right" data-text-color="#000000" data-share-shape="round-rectangle" data-sn-ids="fb.vk.ps.gp.tw." data-share-size="40" data-background-color="#373737" data-preview-mobile="false" data-mobile-sn-ids="fb.vk.tw.wh.ok.vb." data-pid="1534893" data-counter-background-alpha="1.0" data-following-enable="false" data-exclude-show-more="true" data-selection-enable="true" class="uptolike-buttons" ></div>


<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Можно просто код вставить после 6ого дива)

Comment: спс, а можно по-подробнее ?

Comment: Вы вчера задавали этот же вопрос

Comment: код верен, на первый взгляд. Выведите $i на каждой итерации. Еще лучше - покажите весь соседний код из этого файла.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын Если я Вас правильно понял то нужно проверить условие посредством кода: <?php if(count($this->items)): ?> 
<div class="tagItemList">
    <?php 
          $i = 0; 
          foreach($this->items as $item): 
                  $i++;
                  echo "i = ".$i." ";
    ?>     В результате данной проверки видно что i идет не по порядку. То есть последовательность начиная с первого элемента может быть такой к примеру i=1 , i=24, i=14, i=28 . Соседний код отвечает за вывод самих элементов: изображение, описание и т.д. Это если ковырять только код админки...

Comment: Возможно нужен альтернативный способ организации вывода div

Comment: @Ivan $i должны идти по порядку, исходя из представленного кода. Поэтому хочется увидеть код дальше, код всего foreach до конца: там может переопределяться $i, к примеру. Или еще несколько вариантов того, что там может мешать работе.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын понял. отредактировал вопрос и добавил весь код. Спасибо

Comment: @Ivan отформатируйте код. Я бы сделал это сам, но в текущем виде он вообще неадекватен.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын сделал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теперь, когда вы представили весь код, все встало на свои места.

foreach у вас достаточно большой и переменная $i определена ниже, что и мешает работе. Просто переименуйте `$i` у себя в `$counter`, к примеру.

В будущем - не называйте такими банальными именами, как $i служебные переменные в случаях, подобных этому. Потому что с огромной долей вероятности такое имя переменной уже используется где-то рядом и может возникнуть конфликт.

Comment: Большое спасибо что указали на ошибку! Я до этого пихал этот $counter и ничего из этого не вышло. Потому как $counter тоже уже используется. Но благодаря тому что ткнули до меня дошло! обозначил $y все заработало! Спс!

Comment: @Ivan я проверил, в коде $counter не нашел... Ну да неважно. Главное разобрались)